# Error while compile Flutter example project Gradle Zip?

Tags: gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

i create flutter project with "Flutter create myapp" and "cd myapp", and the next i'll try run Flutter Run, but my output is:

[image]

I have a current stable version of Flutter and the recent sdk Android Q published.

This is my flutter doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.18363.657], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (18 hours ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.42.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM J610G • 061f9b46 • android-arm • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: It looks highly related to this issue when you try to run an old project: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40517

Comment: Please make sure to share logs in text format, instead of screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can't copy the first output, because it i put the image, the second output i got copied.

Comment: But how my project can be old if my version is the most recent of flutter and android? Did not make sense.